# How to retrieve correct path of either system32 or SysWOW64?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, win64

I have a 32-bit process that can run either in 32-bit or 64-bit Windows. So, naturally, if the process tried to access the file `c:\windows\system32\file.ext`, it would be redirected to `c:\windows\SysWOW64\file.ext`. So far so good - I don't want to disable the redirection.

My problem is that my process doesn't actually **access** the file - instead it just takes its path and **writes it into a text file**, and I want that text file to read `SysWOW64` on a 64-bit system, and `system32` on a 32-bit system. How can I do that?

Comment: What language are you using?  C/C++/C#?  .Net, Boost, STL?

Comment: Oops, I knew I'd forget something :)
Undecided between Python, C# and a simple batch file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting syswow64 directory using 32-bit application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540930/getting-syswow64-directory-using-32-bit-application)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code will return the correct system directory (system32\syswow64):

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
public static extern bool SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
    IntPtr hwndOwner, [Out]StringBuilder lpszPath, int nFolder, bool fCreate
);

public static string GetSystemDirectory()
{
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(260);
    NativeMethods.SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, path, 0x0029, false);
    return path.ToString();
}
```

On x86 you'll get %windir%\System32
On X64 you'll get %windir%\SysWow64

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer although it suggests the same solution as the other answer, because it provides a working code snippet.
Thanks!

Comment: In .NET 4.0 and higher you can do this: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86)

Answer (score 4):

if I understood it correctly, you can use [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204(VS.85).aspx) passing CSIDL_SYSTEMX86 to the csidl parameter. The documentation for the [valid **csidl's**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457(v=VS.85).aspx) states that a 32 bit process will get:

- **%windir%\system32** on a 32 bits OS
- **%windir%\syswow64** on a 64 bits OS

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

System32 C:\Windows\System32 Windows System folder (system directory) for 64-bit files 
SysWOW64 C:\Windows\SysWOW64 Windows System folder (system directory) for 32-bit files 
Program Files C:\Program Files Folder for 64-bit program files 
Program Files (x86) C:\Program Files (x86) Folder for 32-bit program files