# Compiling 32-bit programs and calling 64-bit programs on 64-bit systems

Tags: c++, go

My system is 64 bit.
I have a program calls a command "bcdedit.exe"

c++ code：

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "cmd.exe", "/c bcdedit.exe /?", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I compiled to 32 bit
When I run it back "file not find"
When I compiled to 64 bit, run passed

The same problem exists in go
go code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe","/c","bcdedit.exe /?")
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

I found "bcdedit.exe" in another directory:

```
C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\amd64_microsoft-windows-b..iondata-cmdlinetool_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.471_none_69b0e05efb5a4702\\bcdedit.exe
```

When I call the command in this directory, all passed
This directory is different on every PC

How do I run the 32-bit compiled program for this command on each PC

Comment: why don't you just compile the app as a 64-bit one? And **don't use the A version of APIs nowadays**. Use the `W` version instead, because the A one will be internally converted to `W` which was CPU time

Comment: Why are you executing `cmd.exe` at all? You should be executing `bcdedit.exe` directly instead. And you should be using `CreateProcess()` for that, not `ShellExecute()`

Answer (score 0):

So your code attempts to launch `"bcdedit.exe"`.  From the command line, the only location of `bcdedit.exe` in your PATH environment is the Windows System directory, `c:\Windows\System32`.

When you compile your code as 32-bit and run it on a 64-bit system, your process's view of the file system will change.  Namely, the process view of the `C:\Windows\System32` is replaced by the contents of `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` - where only 32-bit DLLs and EXEs are located. However.... There is no 32-bit version bcdedit.exe located in this folder. (If you want to simulate this, go run c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe - you won't be able to find bcdedit.exe in the c:\windows\system32 folder anymore).

You probably need something like this: [How to retrieve correct path of either system32 or SysWOW64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094520/how-to-retrieve-correct-path-of-either-system32-or-syswow64)

Format your ShellExecute function to directly specificy the SysWow64 path for both bcdedit.exe and cmd.exe.  Or as others have suggested, just compile for 64-bit.